# convert iso to utc format in java

Tags: java, date, utc, iso

I'm getting below exception while converting date string from `ISO` to `UTC` format in java, what I'm doing wrong here? Please find my code below:

**Test.java**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String date="2020-11-02T07:00:00.114";
        String result = LocalDateTime.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toString();
        System.out.println("result: "+result);
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-11-02T07:00:00.114' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2049)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at test.service.Test.main(Test.java:11)
```

Comment: If you want to convert to UTC, you also need to specify which time zone you want to convert *from*. Your code will assume the string was already in UTC and will perform no conversion.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime
.parse( "2020-11-02T07:00:00.114" ) 
.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC )
.toString()
```

> 2020-11-02T07:00:00.114Z

## Details

You said:

> converting date string from ISO to UTC format

That does not exactly make sense.

- There is an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defining sensible formats for exchanging date-time values textually. These standard formats are used by default when parsing/generating text.
- There is no such thing as "UTC format". UTC is the temporal prime meridian, against which all time zones are defined. The rules for a time zone specify an offset-from-UTC in effect as a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind UTC. But this has nothing to with "formats" of text.

As for parsing your input string as a `LocalDateTime` object, there is no need to bother with defining a formatting pattern. Your string complies with ISO 8601, so it can be parsed directly.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2020-11-02T07:00:00.114" ) ;
```

Your string, and a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) object, represent a date with a time-of-day. But both lack the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

Apparently you know that the publisher of your input string intended that to be a moment as seen from an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC. So we can assign a [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) to get [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

To generate text representing that moment in ISO 8601 format, simply call `toString`.

```
String output = odt.toString() ;
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/cbaHhy).

> 2020-11-02T07:00:00.114Z

Notice the `Z` on the end, pronounced “Zulu”. That is an abbreviation for an offset of zero, `+00:00`.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern ends in `ss`, in other words: In seconds. Your input then has still more stuff.

DateTimeFormatter doesn't take a wild stab at it - it either matches properly or it does not parse. It looks like those are intended to be milliseconds; toss `.SSS` at the end of your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the format of:

`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`

However are specifying a string with fractions of a second 2020-11-02T07:00:00.**114**.

That is parsing whole seconds, but there is still more in the time string.

You need format of:

`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS`